# PHP Template system output

Tags: php, database

I'm using template system in php, so my code is like that for example...

```
$template->addVar ( 'thenameoftemplate', 'thenameofsubtemplate',"what to output");
```

And this code i output in the html file like... `{thenamefsubtemplate}`..

But i have a problem, when i try to output from database something with in the template like the above example but from database, it isn't working, only 1 output from the rows, but when echo it outside of the template it works..

I tryed to output with, foreach,while eaven with for from the database and output it in the template but it's showing just one result.

How to fix that, i wan't to row all the result and output them .

**Update**

Actualy i don't know what is the template system, some script was gaved to me and.. everythingwas ok until the database output..

Here is my last try with the for..

```
if (check_group_access_bool('show_admin_panel_button')) {
            $template->addGlobalVar('admin','<BR><a href="/users/download_list/'. $user[0]['id'] .'.html">Ð²Ð¸Ð¶ ÑÐ¼ÑŠÐºÐ²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ Ð¿ÐµÑÐ½Ð¸</a><BR><img src="/images/icons/edit-user-32x32.png" hspace="2" alt="Ñ€ÐµÐ´Ð°ÐºÑ‚Ð¸Ñ€Ð°Ð¹" align="absmiddle"><a href="/admin/edit_user/'. $user[0]['id'] .'.html">Ñ€ÐµÐ´Ð°ÐºÑ‚Ð¸Ñ€Ð°Ð¹</a>');
}
            $sudtwo = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
$fvsmt = mysql_query("select * from fav where user_id=$sudtwo");
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['id'])){

while($rowings = mysql_fetch_array($fvsmt)) {
$template->addVar( 'userprofile', 'userprofiletwo',"<tr><th nowrap valign=\"TOP\" align=\"LEFT\">  ñòèë: ".$rowings['name']." <form method=\"post\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"premahni ot liubimi\" name=\"del\"></form>></th></tr>");

if(isset($_POST['del']))
{
mysql_query("DELETE FROM fav WHERE name_id=".$rowings['name_id']."");



}
echo"".$rowings['name']."<br>";

}
}
```

This is in the php and here is the HTML

```
<template:tmpl name="userprofile">
{USERPROFILETWO}
</template:tmpl>
```

That's how it outputs..

In the php code, where is my echo it works, but here in the html outputs only one row.

Comment: what are you trying to output from the database? post the relevant bits of your code here.

Comment: You need to show us some code and which template system you are using.

Comment: What template is it? Why is it so secret?

Comment: which templating system you are using?

Comment: If you need to add additional information, please just edit your question. You can use the comment feature to request clarification on any answers that you receive. Please, the answer field is reserved just for answers to your question.

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** OK, you're using something called [patTemplate](http://www.php-tools.de/site.php), which hasn't been updated in a few years. I found some [documentation](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Simple-PHP-Templates-With-PatTemplate/2/) though, and once you've set up your PHP correctly, this in your html should work:

```
<table> 
  <patTemplate:tmpl name="userprofile"> 
    {userprofiletwo}
  </patTemplate:tmpl>
</table>
```

BUT, your PHP is a bit of a mess. What you have is basically:

```
for () {
  $rowings = ...;
  //you are overwriting the variable each time here
  $template->addVar('userprofile', 'userprofiletwo', $rowings); 
}
```

And I think what you want is something like:

```
$rowings = array();
for () {
  // make an array of your data
  $rowings[] = ...;
}
// and call addVar *once*
$template->addVar('userprofile', 'userprofiletwo', $rowings);
```

Now {userprofiletwo} is an array, and you can loop over that in your template.

Also, I'm not sure what the purpose of this bit of code is:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['id'])){
}
```

as it doesn't really do anything...

Comment: But .. it gives error.

Call to undefined method patTemplate::append()

Comment: Without SEEING the code of your templating engine, no one can tell you how to append rows from the db instead of outputting a single row.

Comment: updated my answer to reflect the code and error information provided by the requester

Comment: didn't work, again only one row.. about the session, tha was a mistake there, i edited the post. Still looking for answer.. And the output is actualy from db, not an array but i jusst tryed with for, becouse of that i made it that way. BUt here is edited version with while.Again thanks for trying to help

Comment: You can't just keep adding a scalar value for rowings over and over again inside the loop - this is overwriting your template variable 'userprofiletwo'. when you're inside the loop, add your tr html chunk into a holding array (call it $tableData or something), then after the loop, assign that using addVar. Doesn't matter what sort of loop you use - calling addVar inside the loop will not give you an array in 'userprofiletwo'